# Can't find simbol error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been experimenting with java.util.scanner, and I got an error, can you help...

```
The error as said in Command Prompt:
 18: error :cannot find simbol
   if (answer.equalsignoreCase("yes));
       ^
symbol: variable answer
```

That is the error I get from Command Prompt, and here is the code I wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
class bikeGame {
 public static void main(String[] args){

 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 boolean brakes = false;
 byte speed = 5;
 byte gear = 1;

 String start = " Your current speed is 5km/h. You are in the first gear.";
 String welcome = "Welcome to Bike Rider! You can use the commands 'faster', 'slower' and 'brakes'. Type   'start' to begin...";
 String die = "You died, type 'start' to play again...";
 System.out.println(welcome);
 String input = scanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("You selected " + input + "? Is this correct? <true or false>");
 if (answer.equalsgnoreCase("yes"));
 System.out.println(start);
 float b;
 float c;
 float d; 



 Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 b = myScanner.nextFloat();
 c = myScanner.nextFloat();
 d = myScanner.nextFloat();



 }
}
```

If you see the problem, please don't hesitate to answer...

Comment: You could at least post the error... "I get an error" isn't helpful

Comment: Please read the bottom line...

Comment: what is this: `if (answer.equalsgnoreCase("yes"));` an condition that does nothing, but calls and function, that we don´t know anything about of an object (answer) that is nowhere declared...

Comment: Instead of `answer` use `input`.

Comment: @user2483123 What bottom line?

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared the variable `answer` , but used it :

```
if (answer.equalsgnoreCase("yes"));
```

Perhaps , you wanted to name `input` as `answer` ?

**P.S. :** It is not `.equalsgnoreCase()` , it's `.equalsIgnoreCase()`.